# How to convert rust string to i8(c_char) array?

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I'm using rust to call c++, there are structs generated by `bindgen` and `cc`. The struct fields type is like `[i8;11]` or `[i8;n]`. I want to set these fields.
How to write a common function to transform rust `String/CStr/CString` to `i8`/`c_char` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems you have to be aware of:

- null terminations: Rust strings aren't null-terminated, C/C++ strings are.
- Encoding: Rust strings are UTF-8 encoded, C/C++ string encoding depends on the operating system. On most systems, C/C++ strings are also UTF-8, but on Windows, it is most likely something else, like Windows-1252. In that case you need an external library like [`encoding_rs`](https://docs.rs/encoding_rs/) to convert the encoding properly.

Let's assume C/C++ strings are also encoded in UTF-8 (again, an assumption you can **not** make on Windows). Then, you can convert it (for example) like that:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;

fn main() {
    // Fill with dummy data to 'simulate' the situation of uninitialized memory
    let mut c_array = [42i8; 11];

    // The data that should get written into c_array
    let rust_string = String::from("Hello!");

    // Convert to CString, required for FFI
    let rust_cstring = CString::new(rust_string).unwrap();
    // Extract null-terminated raw data
    let byteslice = rust_cstring.as_bytes_with_nul();

    // Write data. Note that this will panic if `byteslice` is longer than `c_array`.
    let mut byteslice_iter_i8 = byteslice.iter().map(|v| *v as i8);
    c_array[0..byteslice.len()].fill_with(|| byteslice_iter_i8.next().unwrap());

    println!("{:?}", c_array);
}
```

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33, 0, 42, 42, 42, 42]
```

There are of course other ways, and this one probably isn't the absolute single best way to do that, but I hope that this managed to demonstrate the basic principle.